# $X^K$ a Kan complex, without model structure or anodyne extensions

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

If $X$ is a Kan complex, then it is an easy consequence of the existence of the Quillen model structure or of the basic theory of anodyne extensions, that $X^{K}$ is also Kan. However, I am interested in a "direct" proof of this fact, appealing to neither of the above (which is apparently how these sorts of things were proved before Gabriel-Zisman).

Here is the argument I would like to complete:

Let $X$ be a Kan complex, and let $K$ be any simplicial set. It suffices to show that $Hom(K\times \Delta^{n},X) \rightarrow Hom(K \times \Lambda_{k}^{n},X)$ is surjective for all horn inclusions. Since $K\simeq \text{colim}_{m} sk_{m}(K)$ is a filtered colimit, the claim follows if 
$$Hom(sk_{m}(K)\times \Delta^{n},X) \rightarrow Hom(sk_{m}(K) \times \Lambda_{k}^{n},X)$$ is surjective for all $m \ge 0$. Proceed by induction. The base case is easy, but the induction step is what's giving me trouble. By the induction hypothesis, we can choose a solution

$$ h: sk_{m-1}K \times \Delta^{n} \rightarrow X$$

to the lifting problem

$\require{AMScd}$
$\begin{CD}
sk_{m-1}K \times \Lambda^{n}_{k} @>>> sk_{m}K \times \Lambda^{n}_{k} @>f>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
sk_{m-1}K \times \Delta^{n} @>>> sk_{m}K \times \Delta^{n} \\
\end{CD}$

However, as the square above is not a pushout, we can't immediately get a solution to the lifting problem of interest. Now my thought is that maybe there's some way to directly construct the desired lift $g:sk_{m}K \times \Delta^{n} \rightarrow X$ from $f$ and $g$, since all we need to do is specify the images of the nondegenerate simplices of $sk_{m}K \times \Delta^{n}$ which are in neither $sk_{m-1}K \times \Delta^{n}$ nor $sk_{m}K \times \Lambda_{k}^{n}$. However, this is where I run into a wall, as I don't know a simple way to describe these.

Ideally, I would like to see this induction step completed. Does anyone have a solution to this or suggestions for possible solutions? It would be just as well if someone knows a different but equally "direct" argument, not appealing to the machinery mentioned above.

Comment: I would try this - $K$ is a $\varinjlim$ of a diagram of simplices, so the problem should be reducible to lifting along $\Delta^m\times\Lambda^n_k\hookrightarrow\Delta^m\times\Delta^n$; the latter are in turn explicit gluings of simplices, so this lifting problem should be reducible to gradual applications of the Kan property of $X$. Equivalently, one might try to show that $X^{\Delta^m}$ is a Kan complex by explicitly describing $n$-simplices of it as certain explicit compatible families of $m+n$-simplices of $X$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the 'usual' way is as suggested by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე. This is based on a systematic analysis of the simplices of $\Delta^m\times \Delta^n$ and of those missing in the corresponding subcomplex involving the k-horn of $\delta^n$. This sort of thing is classically well known and is based on collapsing arguments from `combinatorial' topology.  It is handled in great detail in Peter May's Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology, starting on page 16.

Comment: There is also an alternative, slightly more conceptual, argument in Appendix H of Joyal's _The Theory of Quasi-categories and Its Applications_.

Comment: This is just the sort of argument I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: As Karol's comment makes clear this is a very useful piece of machinery.  I have been trying to develop non-additive shuffle products in other settings and the anlysis of just such fillling arguments is very important in that context.

Comment: It seems somewhat odd to me that if we tried to do some hard combinatorics in the "proof" I provided above, we would end up having proved the claim without needing the induction argument at all. Also, what are those other contexts you mention?

Comment: Here is one such context: Have a look at Kan's formula for a Samelson product that can be found in Curtis's survey from way-back! No proof was published but it requires a detailed analysis of shuffles. (For more details glance at my question 296479 posted back in March.  NB No one answered it!)

Comment: In some way my answer does use anodyne extensions, but the method does not need their theory just the idea of horns and fillers.  As to your point about the induction, I think it is being hidden since one has to build the overall filler by induction up the skeleton of the prism.  (I learnt that technique as a doctoral student as I had to learn a lot of geometric topology (GT) where it is frequently used. Perhaps the time to revisit the older simplicial set techniques of GT is near.)

Comment: To be fair, I don't think it is accurate to say that this approach avoids "the theory of anodyne extensions". In both cases, we prove that the pushout product of $\partial \Delta[m] \to \Delta[m]$ and $\Lambda^{k}[n] \to \Delta[n]$ is anodyne which I is pretty much "the fundamental lemma of the theory of anodyne extensions".

Comment: Arguments of May and Joyal are combinatorial and very explicit while the argument of Gabriel and Zisman is categorical but still quite explicit. In the grand scheme of things they amount to the same. Of course, for some specialized purposes the combinatorial argument will be more appropriate.

Comment: @KarolSzumiło In category-theoretic context I think the reformulation is this: in a category without products, how *exactly* a product of representables is given by a colimit of representables? You are fine if you can prove that the corresponding diagram of representables is "contractible", without actually computing it, but you might want to know its exact shape all the same.

Comment: @Karol. I think my idea would be that to say that 1+1=2 uses the commutativity law for addition would be a bit strong! Similarly you do not have to know anything about the notion of 'anodyne extension' to work out that you can fill the relevant prisms. You can give an 'almost algorithm' for it. I say 'almost' because in $X$ we know that fillers exist but then we have to choose one so at each stage of filling the prism a choice has to be made.  Extension up the skeleton pre-existed Gabriel and Zisman's use of the term `anodyne extension'.

Comment: @TimPorter Is the filling method you refer to here the one found in May’s text?

Comment: @LPK I am not sure as it is ages since I looked at that part of Peter May's book in detail. The actual filling method is not that important as there are various choices of approach to be made. If I was looking to give some lectures on this I would attempt to give the idea behind the method.  Looking at low dimensional cases first you can see the relationships between the different simplices in a prism. You can analyse this best using shuffles.  Shuffles form a poset and examining that you should be able to see how to proceed. You can then compare with Peter May's method.